# Rules for post-increment and pre-increment operations in java

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment

Oh, I've something missed with this example...

```
int a=1;
int b=1;
int c=1;
System.out.println(a+++b---c++);
```

Is not it the same as next?

```
System.out.println( (a++) + (b--) - (c++) );
```

It seems the result is 0, but that's definitely wrong, so what's going on here?

Comment: Answer is 1 only http://ideone.com/0DleI4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get `1` (and that's what I expect, `1 + 1 - 1` is `1`). Using the eclipse indenter (and adding output for `a` `b` and `c` after the operation)

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;
System.out.println(a++ + b-- - c++);
System.out.printf("a=%d b=%d c=%d%n", a, b, c);
```

I see

```
1
a=2 b=0 c=2
```

And, the *reason* is that post increment doesn't take effect until the next statement. While pre increment (for example, `++a`) takes effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

By using debugger i watch all variables for following to expression

a=b=c=1

A.   `a++ + b-- - c++` = 1 + 1- 1 =0

After A => a=2 b=0 c=2

B.   `(a++) + (b--) - (c++)` = 2 + 0 - 2

After B=> a=3 b=-1 c=3

There is no difference between `a++ + b-- - c++`  and `(a++) + (b--) - (c++)` when we execute these expression in different class there is same result for same input.